# JAVA - Out Of Memory Error while writing Excel Cells in jxl

Tags: excel, memory, memory-management, cells, jxl

I am using JXL to write an excel file of 50000 rows and 30 columns.
My code looks like this:

for (int j = 0; j < countOfRows; j++) {

```
myWritableSheet.addCell(new Label(0, j, myResultSet.getString(1), myWritableCellFormat));

myWritableSheet.addCell(new Label(1, j, myResultSet.getString(2), myWritableCellFormat));

.....

.....
```

}

While writing the cells, the program goes slower and slower

and finally around the row 25000 I am getting the following error:

*Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.getRowRecord(WritableSheetImpl.java:984)
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.addCell(WritableSheetImpl.java:951)
    at KLL.ConverterMainFrame$exportToXLSBillRightsThread.run(ConverterMainFrame.java:6895)*

It's always difficult in Java to handle the memory.

In this case it seems to be the jxl's problem.

Is there a way to write the file, clear the memory and coninue writing cells every 1000 cells?

Would that be a good idea or what else would you propose as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is raising the memory available to the VM (with -Xms and -Xmx) not an option?

Answer (score 6):

The [JExcel FAQ](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/) has a couple of suggestions including Curtis' idea above.

If you don't mind the performance hit, you could use a [temporary file instead of doing it all in memory](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/WorkbookSettings.html#setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(boolean)).

```
WorkbookSettings s = new WorkbookSettings();  
s.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);  
WritableWorkbook ws = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("someFile.xls"),s);
```

Comment: I can't find setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite in the WorkbookSettings Object.
What version of jxl do you have?
(See an answer I posted below for more info)

Comment: @Stefanos, according to the javadocs, it looks like that feature is available in verison >= 2.6.9